# @import "./assets/scss/style" causes application to crash

Tags: vue.js, webpack, sass-loader

I have a vue js project that crashes once I use `@import "./assets/scss/style";`

in first photo the application crashes but one I remove the import it works.

How can I solve this?

[image: Here with import it crashes and shows this error]

[image: Here after removed the import, the application runs with warnings but doesn't crash]

Comment: does `style.scss` have any imports?

Comment: it has these imports 
import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@ import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
/* === SCSS Compass Functions === */
@ import "../../../node_modules/compass-mixins/lib/compass";
@ import "../../../node_modules/compass-mixins/lib/animate";

/*-------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* === Boostrap Main SCSS === */
@ import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap"; 
There is no spaces between @ and import in real code but I added it this way because stackoverflow showed me error @EricGuan

Comment: Please see this thread: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/439. It sounds like you may need to run npm updates and/or install babel-loader. Otherwise I'd recommend double checking the path reference on your imports.